# Responsive facebook like box for iphone

Tags: css, facebook, responsive-design, facebook-likebox

I'm developing a website in Foundation, I wanted to make everything responsive so I put this in my CSS (the first ones are my tries)

```
.fb-like-box, ._8u, ._42ef, ._5g24, ._5kbs, ._5g24._5kbs,
.pluginLikeboxStream, .fb_iframe_widget, .fb_iframe_widget span,
.fb_iframe_widget span iframe[style] {
    width: 100% !important;
}

fb-comments, .fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe[style] {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Well, it works for facebook comments, but not for the Facebook Like Box, which destroys my layout. you can see the website [here](http://www.mentezero.it/)
thanks in advance.